# SSL exception when calling web service from server

Tags: java, apache, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I'm consuming a web service in a java class standalone and it works fine.
I deployed that class as a part of a web-app in tomcat apache and it works fine.

Then, I deployed it in a glassfish server and I get this error:

```
    WSS1601: Transport binding configured in policy but incoming message was not SSL enabled
```

I have several weeks stuck here. Seems like some glassfish setting doesn't accepts that my web-app uses a web service that works through HTTP (this is, and has to be the case).

The webservice client was made with the web service client wizard tool of netbeans (it uses wsimport-JAX-WS). More details on the error trace from the server:

```
    com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: WSS1601: Transport binding configured in policy but incoming message was not SSL enabled
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.policy.verifier.MessagePolicyVerifier.verifyPolicy(MessagePolicyVerifier.java:125)
```

Has anybody else faced this issue?
Any help or ideas appreciated.

---

EDIT: I tried generating the stubs using the axis2 tool and it works great, so i'm sensing some kind of error in jax-ws when used in glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to access the service enables with SSL. Try invoking the service with https also you have to install the valid SSL certificate in the client JDK.
The following link explain how to obtain and install a signed certificate :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1794/aeogl/index.html

Good luck :)

Comment: That's the problem, the service works only through http, and not https